# https request failing in WP8.1 Cordova App

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, https, sencha-touch

I have developed an app using Sencha Touch 2.4.1 and built using Cordova 3.5.0-0.2.7 for Windows Phones. The app make https OData requests to a Server with valid and Trusted SSL certificate, but these requests are failing in WP8.1 with Status Code 0 and Status Text as blank.

It works fine with http protocol in WP8.1 and http/https in WP8.0 as well. Below is a sample code with two buttons-One calls HTTP service(Working) while another calls HTTPS service(Not Working):

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'HTTP',
    handler: function(b, e){
        var storeRef = Ext.getStore('ODataStore');
        storeRef.getProxy().setUrl("http://myDomain:80/SAP/Odata_Service");
        storeRef.load();
    }
},
{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'HTTPS',
    handler: function(b, e){
        var storeRef = Ext.getStore('ODataStore');
        storeRef.getProxy().setUrl("https://myDomain:443/SAP/Odata_Service");
        storeRef.load();
    }
}
```

I think it has to do something with Cordova code. I've seen a few posts with similar problems but no concrete solution.

Comment: please share your config.xml....I think your app is unable to use device's network.

Comment: @sunil The app is working with http/https on WP8.0 and with http on WP8.1, So I think it's not the issue with any configuration file rather it's something related to Cordova support for WP8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem came out to be very strange:**

In first call, Windows Phone 8.1 is not allowing ‘https’ with ‘API Server Credentials’ passed in url . While, It’s allowing https without credentials or http with credentials.

**Workaround:**

I made a dummy call in start with https and no credentials, followed by normal https calls with credentials. It worked!